# Vector Distance

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, analytic-geometry

let there be a line L: $\frac{x-1}{2}= \frac{y+1}{3}= \frac{z}{1}$ and a plane: $2x-y-z=5$. With this given data find: a line L1, such that L1 is parallel to L, is in P, and the distance between L and L1 is d.

I did manage to find d , which is $\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}$. I have no ideas as to how to continue this however.

Comment: How did you come up with the conclusion that $d$ is exactly $\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}$?

Comment: point to plane distance, it's fairly simple

Comment: What point are you referring to? None is mentioned in your question...

Comment: you get the point from the line equation....are you not familiar with this stuff?

Comment: You are given a line and a plane. They are parallel. And you are told to find another line in the plane that is parallel to the one given (infinitely many parallels in the plane) and at a given distance (none if the distance is too short, one if it coincides precisely with the distance between the line and the plane or wo if it is bigger). What am I missing?

Comment: You computed a distance, but from $L$ to the plane. Your question says that the distance is from $L$ to $L_1$. And that could result in none, one or two lines.

Comment: @AugSB I also understood that all in all you're not really familial with the  material in the above question.

Comment: Please, do not try to cast doubt on what I do or do not know. You have to compute the projection of the line on the plane. But that is what I had to extract from your comments; it is not what your question says.

Answer (score 1):

First, let us write the line in an easier (for me, at least) way:

$$3x-3=2y+2=6z\implies\begin{cases}x=2z+1\\{}\\y=3z-1\end{cases}\;\implies\;\ell:\;(1,-1,0)+t(2,3,1)\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R$$

As it should be because of the problem requirements, check we have that $\;\ell\parallel\pi\;$. A parametric representation for the plane could be:

$$\begin{cases}A=(3,1,0)\\B=(2,0,-1)\\C=(0,-4-1)\end{cases}\in\pi\implies\pi:\;B+t\vec{BA}+s\vec{BC}\;,\;\;t,s\in\Bbb R\implies$$

$$\pi:\;(2,0,-1)+t(1,1,1)+s(-2,-4,0)$$

The wanted distance between $\;\ell,\,\pi\;$ is the distance of *any* point on the line to the plane, so for example let us take the point $\;(1,-1,0)\;$ so its distance to $\;\pi\;$ is:

$$d=\frac{|2+1+0-5|}{\sqrt6}=\frac2{\sqrt6}=\sqrt\frac23$$

Try to take it from here. The continuation may now depend heavily, in my opinion, in what you know/prefer. You could take any point on the line $\;\ell\;$ and look at its orthogonal projection on the plane $\;\pi\;$ and then choose the line on the plane thorugh the foot of that projection on the plane, or you could set an equation for a general point in the plane which is at distance $\;d\;$ from say $\;(1,-1,0)\in\ell\;$ and solve with differential calculus.